# JavaFx layout missbeheavior with prefered size and min Size

Tags: javafx, layout, resize, fxml

Disclaimer: I am a JavaFx beginner and come from the wpf world

I have a problem with the behavior of the prefered height and the max height. The min height is ignored and the prefered height is used. What do i wrong?

Code Example: (this is only to illustrate the problem)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox fx:controller="sample.Controller" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Pane minHeight="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightblue;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <Pane fx:id="buttonPane" style="-fx-background-color: lightgreen;">
         <children>
            <Button minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0"  onAction="#buttonPaneClick" prefHeight="200.0" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

[image]

Problem: the Button is only half showed and not scaled down. But the min height is 0 so i would expectd that the button goes to 0 when not more place is available but he is cropped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`Pane` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html):

> This class may be used directly in cases where absolute positioning of children is required since **it does not perform layout beyond resizing resizable children to their preferred sizes**.

(my emphasis).

So the `Pane` containing the button will resize it to its preferred size no matter what. If you replace the pane containing the button with a layout container that does more layout than this (e.g. a `HBox`) then you will see the behavior you are expecting:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Pane minHeight="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightblue;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <HBox fx:id="buttonPane" style="-fx-background-color: lightgreen;">
         <children>
            <Button minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0"  prefHeight="200.0" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```